# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, database, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table `A` having columns `name(string), email(sring) and details(json)`. I want to use first_or_create like this:

`A.where(:name => a.name, :email => a.email, :details => a.details).first_or_create`

But this gives the following error:

`PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "details"`

Can't we query like the above if we have a json type column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out, for JSON, the query will be like this:

`A.where("name=? and email=? and details->>'key1'=? and details->>'key2'=?", a.name, a.email,a.details["key1"],a.details["key2"])`

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json